# How to update kernel without reboot? (ksplice alternative)

Tags: linux, kernel, upgrade

How to update running kernel without reboot? I know about [Oracle ksplice](http://www.ksplice.com/) but it's not free and it supports only distributions that I don't use. Are there alternatives to ksplice?

Answer (score 6):

The underlying technology is free and part of the mainline kernel; Oracle just provides prebuilt images.  You can build your own ksplice patches to dynamically load into your own kernel.

Comment: That's nice! But where is it in menuconfig or how is it called in .config?

Comment: See the ksplice package.

Comment: Hey, I've posted a follow-up on Ask Ubuntu that you might be able to answer (or help on): http://askubuntu.com/questions/193069/how-can-i-upgrade-my-servers-kernel-without-rebooting

Comment: It might be nice to add more details to this answer instead of creating 2-sentence answers

Answer (score 2):

It is an old question, but it shows up on top of google, and a lot of things has changed since then. Here are ksplice alternatives as of now:

- Livepatch is the technology in mainstream kernel. Canonical provides kernel livepatch service for Ubuntu 16.04 and later. It is free for up to 3 machines for personal use or up to 50 machines if you are a recognised Ubuntu Community member. If you are neither - you can use it for a fee in an Ubuntu Advantage support [subscription](https://ubuntu.com/advantage) ($225-$1,500/machine/year on physical servers, $75-$500/machine/year - on VMs), which is still cheaper than ksplice option. Unlike other solutions in the list, it allows administrators to create their own patches but it can be difficult and time-consuming work. Amazon Linux recently announced [livepatch support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/al2-live-patching.html) (beta) for Amazon Linux 2 as well. No other distros offers live patching services (even though technology is integrated into the kernels) .
- Kpatch is Red Hat’s own rebootless kernel live patching tool based on livepatch. It was announced in 2014. It works on RHEL and its derivative and is available as a part of the Premium support [subscription](https://www.redhat.com/en/store/red-hat-enterprise-linux-server#?sku=RH00003) ($1,299 per year).
- SUSE’s Kgraft live patching solution only supports SUSE’s own Linux Enterprise Server 12. The prices start from $699/year per 2 sockets or $1,890/three years per 2 sockets. They have the longest [trial](https://www.suse.com/products/live-patching/download/) period - 60 days, but there are some limitations from an architectural perspective.
- KernelCare - automated live patching solution, covers most of the popular distributions, including CentOS, RHEL, Oracle Linux, Debian, Ubuntu, Amazon Linux and others. KernelCare also supports the Glibc and OpenSSL patching without a reboot. It also offers custom and fixed-date patching to meet the specific needs. A 30-day [trial](https://www.kernelcare.com/free-trial/) is available and subscription options start from $2.25/server/month for kernel patching only and $5.45/server/month for kernel and Glibc/OpenSSL package.

Comment: there are free options, why do I only see paid services in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to `ksplice` is [`kexec()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec). Rather than patching the Linux kernel whilst running, this command essentially replaces the current kernel with a new one without rebooting your system.

In order for this to be available, it needs to be turned on as a compiler option in your distribution's kernel - that is, you can compile kernels without this functionality, so you'll need to check it is available and/or enable it yourself.

Comment: Replacing the current kernel with a new one effectively *is* rebooting, just without the bother of going through the boot loader.  You still end up having to save your work, shutdown, and restart your applications.

Comment: (debian/ubuntu) kexec-tools appears to not be ported to support systemd at this time; and as far as I know neither current package repository is supporting any init besides systemd; so kexec is off the table in debian land currently;

Comment: @psusi I believe kexec avoids actually powering off the hardware, such that the mainboard does not need to spend time to POST, nor does any pci device need to initialize from scratch - a feature I highly sought after when the hardware takes multiple minutes to cold boot :cry: